# fields are missing in R.java in android

Tags: android

I add some java classes from other application into my android application.But (some fields missing) in R.java error occurs. I cleaned my project but still the same error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: try deleting the r.java , clean and rebuild

Answer (score 2):

If you only added classes you won't get extra resources along with them. You need to either copy the resources or maybe you can include the other classes as a library.

If you copy the resources the classes you copied may also refer to the old project's R in the import. If so you'll need to remove that line and add your own.

Comment: I copied xml and also modified menifest.